# Unable to append RDD to a list in scala

Tags: scala, list

Hi following i am unable to append values to my List in Scala following is my code:

```
var cumFrequency =List[Any]
updatedRdd.foreachRDD( rdd => {
  for( item <- rdd.collect()) {
   val newRDD = (item._1,item._2.toString.toDouble/newc)
    cumFrequency +: newRDD
  }

})
```

I am getting error at `cumFrequency +: newRDD` of can not resolve symbol. i am not sure why its giving that error when i want to append `newRDD` to list `cumFrequency` . am i writing in wrong syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use :+ not +:

Below is the corrected line

```
cumFrequency :+ newRDD
```

Initialise you cumFrequency using `List.empty[Any]` or `List[Any]()`

```
var cumFrequency = List[Any]()
```

or

```
var cumFrequency =List.empty[Any]
```

In order to append to list use `:::` or `++` or `:+`

In case of List try this

```
cumFrequency ::: List(newRDD)
```

or

cumFrequency ++ List(newRDD)

or if you do not care about order then

```
newRDD :: cumFrequency
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work in the context of your program, where the values are added to the list in an imperative style, you need:

```
cumFrequency = cumFrequency ++ List(newRDD)
```

or

```
cumFrequency = newRDD :: cumFrequency
```

And you should also add brackets after the declaration:

```
var cumFrequency =List[Any]()
```

This style is not recommended by most Scala programmers. A better way would be something like:

```
val cumFrequency = updatedRdd.flatMap( rdd => {
  for( item <- rdd) yield (item._1,item._2.toString.toDouble/2)
})
```

But that would depend on the RDD data type, which I'm not familiar with.